# Plagiar a si mesmo? Problemas diferentes, mas respostas iguais

Tags: debate, respostas, perguntas-duplicadas, plágio

Seria errado copiar uma resposta que vc mesmo já deu em outra pergunta e repeti-la na íntegra em uma nova pergunta?

***As vezes em problemas e perguntas diferentes a resposta pode ser a mesma que vc já deu em outra ocasião.***

Exemplo bem básico só para contextualiza.

- Pergunta 1 - A pessoa não consegue fazer uma `div` sobrepor a outra.
- Pergunta 2 - A pessoas tem uma `div` que fica por debaixo das outras.

São duas situações diferentes, mas que a "resposta técnica" seria basicamente igual, com as mesmas fontes (links) e o mesmo exemplo de código provavelmente. *(é só um exemplo ok :p)*

Nesse caso seria errado dar um <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd> em uma resposta antiga sua e um <kbd>ctrl+v</kbd> na nova pergunta?

Ou o indicado seria marcar como "**Duplicada**" só pela resposta ser a mesma, mas o problema ser diferente?

*Obs: fiz uma pesquisa pelo Meta, mas não achei nada referente a isso diretamente.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se você está fazendo isto é porque a pergunta nova é duplicata da antiga. Então não é questão de plágio, é que não precisa de uma nova resposta.

Esta é a definição de duplicata: já existe uma resposta no site que atende a necessidade da nova pergunta. Pode ser estranho, mas são as respostas que indicam se uma pergunta é duplicata ou não.

Comment: Pois é, eu fiquei na dúvida se marco ou não como Duplicada esse tipo de pergunta. As vezes o AP pode não ser muito experiente e pode não entender que mesmo a situação dele sendo diferente a resposta seria a mesma da outra pergunta...